# Need to work out a formula with exponential growth.

Tags: exponentiation

Lets say I start with 10 gold, my income is 15 per hour. I can increase my income with 15 by purchasing an upgrade that costs 30 (as many times as I want).

If i expand this into spreadsheets i can calculate it, but I haven't been able to make a simple formula that can say how much gold i can make total provided i upgrades as soon as i can, then specify time passed and get a result.

Then i suppose i would need a separate one for calculating what my income would be at the time.

Its somewhat similar to doing compound interest = Start Cash * [(1 + Interest)^Times It multiplies – 1]

But apparently I'm not that smart to adjust a formula on the fly. And I can't name exactly what this is supposed to be to spare your time and look for it on google myself.

Though it looks similar to population growth, ill see if i can adapt something from that sphere.

Comment: Do you mean that you buy an upgrade as soon as you generate 30 gold

Comment: Also do you want to calculate total cash or cash generated per hour?

Comment: @h-squared yes as soon as i can buy. 2 - Both i guess. How much i made so far total, and my per hour now.